# Close Windows Media Player with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, media-player

I used `winopen('filename')` to open an AVI file using the Windows Media Player. How can I close it?

Comment: Do you need to use windows media player to open the file? If not, you can just use the "aviread" and "movie" functions in matlab.

Answer (score 3):

There is `tkill` command on Windows to kill a task. You can use it with `system()`. You have to find a method to kill only "your" WMP if several can coexist.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control movie playback in MATLAB, use MATLAB itself to play the movie.

You can use [mmreader](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mmreaderclass.html) to do this. An example is provided in the documentation.

Note that in older versions of MATLAB, you'll need to use `aviread` instead. Also, as mentioned in the above link, `mmreader` is being renamed to `VideoReader` in future versions of MATLAB.

Comment: thanks but I need to use winopen, as I need to get input from the keyboard while the movie is playing, and I didn't menage to do it with aviread() or other matlab functions.

Answer (score 0):

Might be tough to do easily. I thought there would be a way using Matlab's dos command and the appropriate parameters, but the recent version of WMP doesn't have a close after play command (see [WMP Command Line Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa386383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). This is odd, since I found [older documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/241422) that does reference a /close parameter, but it doesn't work with Win7.

If you are desperate, you should be able to use the COM interface to get it done, but this is a trickier task.